# Why &mut self in method when modifying an object as field in a struct

Tags: rust, struct, borrow-checker, mutability

I still struggle to grasp why `&mut self` is required to modify the internal state of an object owned by my struct. I understand why I have to use at least `&self`, because I don't want to consume `self`, ending its existance. I also understand why I have to use `&mut self` if I were modifying fields of my struct, but I don't.

I have the following struct and implementation:

```
struct Writer {
    obj: json::JsonValue
}

impl<'b> Writer {
    fn from(obj: json::JsonValue) -> Self {
        Self {
            obj
        }
    }

    fn put(&mut self, field_name: &str, value: bool) {
        self.obj.insert(field_name, value);
        //   ^^^- not modifying this, but a field inside "obj"
    }

    fn release_ownership(self) -> json::JsonValue {
        self.obj
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
writer.put(field_name, true);
```

With `&self` instead of `&mut self` I'd get a compiler error:

```
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable`
```

The [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#wheres-the---operator) taught me:

> If we wanted to change the instance that we’ve called the method on as part of what the method does, we’d use &mut self as the first parameter.

I don't see how I modify the struct here. I clearly modify a field (here `obj`) *in the struct*, but not the struct itself.

In the [definition of `JsonValue::insert()`](https://docs.rs/json/latest/json/enum.JsonValue.html#method.insert) I can see `&mut self`, which I do not understand either, since it "only" mutates the *contents* of `object` through `JsonValue::Object::insert()`.

The [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html) says:

> Note that the entire instance must be mutable; Rust doesn’t allow us to mark only certain fields as mutable.

I can understand this, if I want to modify field values, but not, if the fields are pointers to other structs that are modified.

My intuition tells me, that me qualifying with `&mut` refers not to the direct reference to data, but to the whole path along all pointers or to the final reference. If this is the case: why is that?

However, it seems redundant, since [`JsonValue::insert()`](https://docs.rs/json/latest/json/enum.JsonValue.html#method.insert) already enforced mutable access to its internal object. So the compiler knows, that the instance of `JsonValue` was mutably borrowed for the insert and can not be borrowed again, until it was released.

Homework: read the book and did my [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+%22%26mut+self%22).

Comment: Are you aking "why" as in "why was this designed this way"?

Comment: Yes. I think cafce25 explained that in their comment to my response in their answer. The compiler does not always have a clear indication that a reference is potentially mutated. So the Rust engineers opted to me explicitly having to declare it. I may certainly help me and the consumers of my functions not to think of various access modes in borrowed values. I guess that's the point here.

Answer (score 5):

Everything along the access chain has to be declared a mutable reference to make sure you can't get two mutable references to the same object. Consider this:

```rust
struct ContainsMutable<'a>(&'a mut i8);

fn main() {
    let mut a = 99;
    let cm = ContainsMutable(&mut a);
    let cmref1 = &cm;
    let cmref2 = &cm;
    // now if both references allowed mutable access to the pointee
    // `a` we'd have a problem because this would be allowed
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            *cmref1.0 = 55;
        });
        s.spawn(|| {
            *cmref2.0 = 31;
        });
    });
}
```

So we can never be allowed mutable acces to something behind a shared reference (something that we accessed through a shared reference somewhere along the path) because we could easily create mutable references to the same object that way.

> However, it seems redundant, since JsonValue::insert() already enforced mutable access to its internal object. So the compiler knows, that the instance of JsonValue was mutably borrowed for the insert and can not be borrowed again, until it was released.

That assumes the compiler can predict at compile time when the function is called and disallow this, but it can't, or that borrow checking is done at runtime, it's not, borrow checking is done statically at compile time. You can get runtime borrow checking with `RefCell`, `Mutex` or a `RwLock`.

Comment: I understand your example. I understand why the compiler see's that `a` is mutably * *borrowed twice** (disallowed by the borrowing rules) via two references to `cm` being captured in the scope. But my point is, that the compiler could assume access **through** `cmref1` and `cmref2` **implicitly** being (potentially) mutable. If we remove all the thread code and sequentially make assignments to the two references in the main thread, the compiler complains about just that. So _it can trace that_.

Comment: No a shared reference always means there could be other references at the same time, that's just how borrowing works in Rust, the compiler doesn't always have such a clear path to the target. A mutable reference is how we programmers tell the compiler that this reference isn't shared and thus safe to mutate through.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question that is bothering you is about the shallow vs deep nature of const-ness/mutability.
Depending upon the programming language, this aspect can be seen differently.
If you have a background in a language where (almost) everything is accessed
via references (Java, JS, Python...), defining a structure with a member
referring to something else can be perceived as if the internal details of
this member are not part of the structure (they are outside the structure).
Consequently, changing something within the internal details of this member
can be seen as **not** mutating the structure.

In C language, this is well known as the shallow constness:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b[3];
} S1;
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int *b;
} S2;
// ...
const S1 s1 = { 11, { 99, 88, 77 } };
// s1.a = 22; // error, a is altered but s1 is const
// s1.b[0] = 33; // error, b is altered but s1 is const 
const S2 s2 = { 11, malloc( ... ) };
// s2.a = 22; // error, a is altered but s2 is const
// s2.b = realloc(s2.b, ... ); // error, b is altered but s2 is const
s2.b[0] = 33; // !!! allowed !!! since b is not altered itself (but what it refers to)
```

In my opinion this is very confusing.

In C++, standard containers prefer deep constness:

```
struct S {
    int a;
    std::vector<int> b;
};
// ...
const S s{ 11, std::vector{99, 88, 77} };
// s.a = 22; // error, a is altered but s is const
// s.b[0] = 33; // error, altering the stored values is an alteration of the member itself
```

In my opinion this is much more consistent and easy to reason about:
« my structure is altered as a whole if I alter any of its parts ».

In Rust, deep constness/mutability applies (as with C++ standard containers).

```rust
struct S1 {
    a: u8,
    b: [u8; 3],
}
struct S2 {
    a: u8,
    b: Box<[u8; 3]>, // we could have used Vec instead
}
let s1 = S1 { a: 11, b: [99, 88, 77] };
// s1.a = 22; // error, a is altered but s1 is not mut
// s1.b[0] = 33; // error, b is altered but s1 is not mut 
let s2 = S2 { a: 11, b: Box::new([99, 88, 77]) };
// s2.a = 22; // error, a is altered but s2 is not mut
// s2.b[0] = 33; // error, b is altered but s2 is not mut
```

For `S1` it's obvious that the array takes place directly inside
the structure, but if we change our mind about the internal details
of the storage, as in `S2`, we probably don't want to change the semantics.
This last example shows that the implementation detail about the way we
store the data for `b` (array, boxed-array, vector...) does not change the semantics: « my structure is altered as a whole if I alter any of its parts ».

Coming back to your original example, the `JsonValue` is a part of your
`Writer` structure, then altering this part should be considered as an
alteration of the whole structure.
This is the safer choice by default.
On the other hand, if you have a good reason to use a very broad semantics
(à la Java, JS, Python...) as if the ownership was not clearly defined but
eventually shared between several containers, or as if anyone could modify
any piece of data at any time, then you can always explicitly opt-in with
`Rc` and `RefCell`.
In my opinion, it is better to start from a very strict and safe semantics
and explicitly opt-in for something less strict if necessary (it's explicit,
anyone can see it in the source code) than the opposite (the language lets
you do anything but you expect nobody will break the strict semantics you
thought about).

Comment: I have a background in all of the mentioned languages, with least confidence in C++, but good enough to understand the concept of pointers and references. And I was thinking in terms of structs containing pointers to other structs. That's why I said `I clearly modify a field (here obj) in the struct, but not the struct itself.` in my question.

Comment: @try-catch-finally Sorry, I really don't understand what you mean by modifying a field in the struct without modifying the struct itself; then my answer is probably not related to your problem...

Comment: @try-catch-finally In your example, the `obj` member is not a pointer (although internally it certainly uses pointers). How could we mutate something inside this member without considering the structure itself has been mutated?